# Python Regex: Backreference a matching regex group

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to return 2 subgroups from my regex match:

```
email_add = "John@Doe.com <John@Doe.com>"
m = re.match(r"(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b) <(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)", email_add)
```

But it doesn't seem to match:

```
>>> m.group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I suspect I probably did not group it correctly or I'm using incorrect word boundary. I tried \w instead of \b but the result is the same.

Could someone please point out my errors.

Comment: Your regex doesn't match the string. You need case-insensitive matching.

Comment: `[A-Z]` won't match lowercase. I suggest to build the regex step by step. And expand the string as you go, taht way you will find your basic mistakes easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are matching uppercase `A-Z` letters *only*, so the character sequences `ohn` and `oe` and `com` cause the pattern not to match anything.

Adding the `re.I` case-insensitive flag makes your pattern work:

```
>>> import re
>>> email_add = "John@Doe.com <John@Doe.com>"
>>> re.match(r"(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b) <(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)", email_add)
>>> re.match(r"(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b) <(\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b)", email_add, re.I)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1030d4f10>
>>> _.groups()
('John@Doe.com', 'John@Doe.com')
```

or you could add `a-z` to the character classes instead:

```
>>> re.match(r"(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b) <(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)", email_add)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1030d4f10>
>>> _.groups()
('John@Doe.com', 'John@Doe.com')
```

Comment: D'oh! Excellent! Thank you Martijn :)

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with your regex has been pointed out, but you may also want to consider `email.utils.parseaddr`:

```
>>> from email.utils import parseaddr
>>> email_add = "John@Doe.com <John@Doe.com>"
>>> parseaddr(email_add)
('', 'John@Doe.com')  # doesn't get first part, so could assume it's same as 2nd?
>>> email_add = "John Doe <John@Doe.com>"
>>> parseaddr(email_add)
('John Doe', 'John@Doe.com') # does get name and email
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I wouldn't have easily stumbled across that neat module alone.